# Gender detection by full name

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I want to create a model that detects the gender based on a full name.
I have two dictionaries with male & female names. I want to develop a model to classify previously unseen names.

I need to determine the gender after the NER (name entity recognition) process. This delivers a PERSON entity with any one of these characteristics:

- FULL NAME (John Travolta)
- NAME only (John)
- SURNAME only (Travolta)

I can do male vs female determination on (given) name only.  The model needs to handle SURNAME only, classifying it as **NO_GENDER**.

I know that surnames can be noisy, but I must deal with them, because they could be a part of the input.

Comment: Okay, you've been given an assignment.  What is the *specific* problem you're having?  Since this class of problem is addressed quite well in readily available literature, on-line classes, videos, etc., I don't see where there's a Stack Overflow question in this.

Comment: @Prune i do not know what approach should i follow to avoid the noise of the surnames. I did not find a paper that takes into the accout the FULL NAME.

Comment: For example...what classifier algorithm should i use in this case.

Comment: Why include the surname in the model at all? Sure it sends it to you, but can't you just ignore it? I doubt surname will ever inform you about gender.

Also, are you given any other sentence context, or just the name?

Comment: @Dail: when you *know* that a feature is *pure* noise, you don't include it in the training at all.  Simply don't include it in the features to consider; that's usually a parameter to the training function.

Comment: @Prune you are right but as i told you my PERSON entity could be FULL NAME or NAME or SURNAME. So when i pass this person entity to the classifier with "Travolta" it will give me MALE or FEMALE outcome, but it is not correct it should be NO_GENDER.

Comment: Ah -- so it has one of the three entries, not all three.

Comment: Does the input include the field name?  For instance, do you get `NAME ONLY Haley` and `SURNAME ONLY Haley`, or simply `Haley`?

Comment: Also, what approaches have you tried?  Simply reading papers rarely hands you a completed solution.

Comment: @Prune The name is not always included, i know there are surnames that look like names too, but i think there is no solution for them. For the moment i have only made a maxent model to classify names but surnames have ruined everything because I have to add a new class (NO_GENDER)

Comment: Beware of edge cases that may confuse your classifier, such as the American preponderance to pick first names that others consider last names (eg Hunter, Jackson). As first names these typically are fairly gender predictive (but obviously not as last names)

Answer (score 1):

First, pre-process the data: in a full-name input, keep only the name (see below).  Apply this to unknown input as well.

I suggest that you train a multi-class SVM.  You already know the three classes.  Make up the following training (labeled) data:

- NO_GENDER: names on both the girls' and boys' lists
- FEMALE: names on only the girls' list
- MALE: names on only the boys' list
- NO_GENDER: known surnames
- NO_GENDER: non-name strings

Essentially,you train this to recognize FEMALE, MALE, and everything else.

**PREPROCESS**

This will give you some troubles, due to varying name formats.  You may have trouble with compound names, such as

```
Bobby Jo             male name with female modifier
van der Waal         compound surname with male-looking prefix
St. John             surname with gendered primary
Haley-Christopher    hyphenated surname, genedered
```

If you pre-process the inputs, you may have some trouble spotting the proper division in, say, `Billy Jean St. John` or `Marie-Therese von Klaus`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It seems a good approach, I only have two questions: (1) with non-name strings do you mean "everything" (a complete dictionary of the language) ? (2) I did not understand how i should only keep the name during the preprocess step. In Italy there are not compound names (they are very very rare). If the input is a "normal" full name like John Travolta how should i remove the surname ?

Comment: (1) Not everything; perhaps as many non-names as you have names.  I would use perhaps a list of common nouns and verbs, as well as some strings of random letters.  This is to help the model build a stronger idea of "everything else".  For instance, I want it to know that "KNL microprocessor" has no gender.
(2) Remove the surname in your input processing layer.  Split the string at the space and keep only the first word.

Comment: that's another problem. The name can be on the left or right of the surname. I cannot simply split the string to get the first token.

Comment: Okay.  In that case, perhaps another attack: *augment* your single-name training data, so that everything is a full-name record.  Make these tuples, using both ("John", "") and ("", John) as training data.  This way, I think you'll get a stronger match to one of the two training cases.

Comment: ok, should i use all the combinations? i mean the combinations of MALE + all the surnames and FEMALE + all the list of surnames

Comment: No.  If your algorithm choice doesn't train properly given a tuple with a "given" name and one blank, then you'll need to switch algorithms.